# Histograms on SQL in Django QuerySet Annotation / Aggregation

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

In "pure" SQL one can execute the following query:

```
SELECT 
count(CASE WHEN Age>= 10 AND Age < 20 THEN 1 END) AS '10 - 20',
count(CASE WHEN Age>= 21 AND Age < 30 THEN 1 END) AS '21 - 30',
count(CASE WHEN Age>= 31 AND Age < 35 THEN 1 END) AS '31 - 35',
count(CASE WHEN Age>= 36 AND Age < 40 THEN 1 END) AS '36 - 40',
FROM (SELECT Age FROM Attendees) AS AgeGroups
```

which essentially allows you to compute histograms of your datasets.

Is there a way to specify that using Django `aggregate()` syntax? Essentially applying arbitrary syntax for filtering aggregations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django does not allow you to do this using the `aggregate` method on queryset objects, as this is more complex than Django is trying to aim for. This may change in the near future with [the improved query APIs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/), allowing for [custom aggregate methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#aggregate-expressions).

Until then, you can do this using Django's [`raw` method on querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/), which allows you to execute arbitrary SQL. Keep in mind that this is not secured by Django, so you need to watch out for any possible issues in your SQL.